# Is it possible to retrieve information about higher-level dependencies whith SpaCy (Python)?

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, spacy

I am working with SpaCy and my problem is that I don't know how to retrieve information about second-level dependencies. I am interested in knowing if a quantifier (e.g. 'every', 'all', 'some') stands in subject or object position; however, if I ask for the dependency of every token, the dependency assigned to the quantifier is 'DET' (determiner):

```
doc = nlp("Mary loves every man")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.dep_)

Mary nsubj 
loves ROOT
every DET
man dobj
```

I would be interested instead in the second-level dependency, that is, I want to know if 'every' is the determiner of an object (as in this case, in which 'every' is the determiner of 'man' that is parsed as a 'dobj') or of a subject.

If you have any other idea for solving the problem, even if they don't involve SpaCy, every information would be very helpful. I have tried to solve the problem in another way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59500488/problem-with-indexes-in-enumerate-python/59501503#59501503) but it was not very successful.

Thank you very much for your help!!!

Comment: I may not be following your question quite closely enough, but it seems to me that you have to look at both words to get your answer (and that this sentence isn't useful in fully explicating the issue). The sentence `All Marys love every man` has two quantifiers, `All` being the determiner of `Marys` and `every` being the determiner of `man`. I would think the answer would be finding all DET objects, then finding the word directly after them, so that you have DET-dobj, DET-nsub, etc. pairs. Then you could find `every` in a sentence to see what it's paired with to get your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To analyze the dependency tree, you need to look at both the dependency relation (`token.dep_`) and the head (token `token.head` with token index `token.head.i`).

```py
doc = nlp("Mary loves every man")
for token in doc:
    print(token.text, token.dep_, token.head.text, token.head.i)
```

Output:

```
Mary nsubj loves 1
loves ROOT loves 1
every det man 3
man dobj loves 1
```

Spacy has a built-in dependency tree visualizer, too:

```py
spacy.displacy.serve(doc)
```

[image: dependency tree for "Mary loves every man"]